# Scala Compiler Plugin - Determine whether method is overridden

Tags: scala, scalac, scala-compiler

I am writing a Scala Compiler Plugin with a component the executes after the "jvm" phase where there is need to know that a method is overridden. Here is a distilled version of a test case I am working on:

```
abstract class GenericController[T] {

    def getPath():String

    def save(entity:T):String = "parent"
}

class StatusController extends GenericController[String] {

    override def getPath():String = "/statuses"

    override def save(entity:String):String = "child"
}
```

When traversing the AST, I iterate over the classes and the methods ensuring that I only process the methods that are not overridden. The `scala.reflect.internal.Symbols.MethodSymbol.overrides()` method applied to the symbol for the `StatusController.getPath` method will include the one for `GenericController.getPath`.

However, the `MethodSymbol.overrides()` fails to return the `GenericController.save` method for the `StatusController.save` symbol. Seem like the generic type complicates this behavior, Should this be done after another compiler phase?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define test compiler plugin.

*core/src/main/scala/Main.scala*

```
abstract class GenericController[T] {
  def getPath():String
  def save(entity:T):String = "parent"
}

class StatusController extends GenericController[String] {
  override def getPath():String = "/statuses"
  override def save(entity:String):String = "child"
}
```

*plugin/src/main/resources/scalac-plugin.xml*

```
<plugin>
    <name>MyCompilerPlugin</name>
    <classname>compilerPlugin.MyCompilerPlugin</classname>
</plugin>
```

*plugin/src/main/scala/compilerPlugin/MyCompilerPlugin.scala*

```
package compilerPlugin

import scala.tools.nsc.{Global, Phase}
import scala.tools.nsc.plugins.{Plugin, PluginComponent}

class MyCompilerPlugin(val global: Global) extends Plugin {
  import global._

  val name = "MyCompilerPlugin"
  val description = "My compiler plugin"
  val components: List[PluginComponent] = List[PluginComponent](MyComponent)

  private object MyComponent extends PluginComponent {
    val global: MyCompilerPlugin.this.global.type = MyCompilerPlugin.this.global
    val runsAfter: List[String] = List[String](/*"typer"*/"jvm")
    val phaseName: String = MyCompilerPlugin.this.name
    def newPhase(_prev: Phase) = new MyPhase(_prev)

    class MyPhase(prev: Phase) extends StdPhase(prev) {
      override def name: String = MyCompilerPlugin.this.name

      def apply(unit: CompilationUnit): Unit = {
        for (tree@q"$mods def $tname[..$tparams](...$paramss): $tpt = $expr" <- unit.body) {
          println(s"tree=$tree, symbol=${tree.symbol.fullName}, symbol.overrides=${tree.symbol.overrides.map(_.fullName)}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*build.sbt*

```
ThisBuild / name := "compiler-plugin-demo"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.13.3",
  version := "1.0",
)

lazy val plugin = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
      scalaOrganization.value % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value,
    )
  )

lazy val core = project
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    scalacOptions ++= Seq(
      "-Xplugin:plugin/target/scala-2.13/plugin_2.13-1.0.jar",
      "-Xplugin-require:MyCompilerPlugin"
    )
  )
```

If you run (sbt `reload; clean; plugin/package; core/compile`) this compiler plugin after `typer` phase it prints

```
tree=def <init>(): GenericController[T] = {
  GenericController.super.<init>();
  ()
}, symbol=GenericController.<init>, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=def getPath(): String, symbol=GenericController.getPath, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=def save(entity: T): String = "parent", symbol=GenericController.save, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=def <init>(): StatusController = {
  StatusController.super.<init>();
  ()
}, symbol=StatusController.<init>, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=override def getPath(): String = "/statuses", symbol=StatusController.getPath, symbol.overrides=List(GenericController.getPath)
tree=override def save(entity: String): String = "child", symbol=StatusController.save, symbol.overrides=List(GenericController.save)
```

but if you run it after `jvm` phase it prints

```
tree=def getPath(): String, symbol=GenericController.getPath, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=def save(entity: Object): String = "parent", symbol=GenericController.save, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=def <init>(): GenericController = {
  GenericController.super.<init>();
  ()
}, symbol=GenericController.<init>, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=override def getPath(): String = "/statuses", symbol=StatusController.getPath, symbol.overrides=List(GenericController.getPath)
tree=override def save(entity: String): String = "child", symbol=StatusController.save, symbol.overrides=List()
tree=override <bridge> <artifact> def save(entity: Object): String = StatusController.this.save(entity.$asInstanceOf[String]()), symbol=StatusController.save, symbol.overrides=List(GenericController.save)
tree=def <init>(): StatusController = {
  StatusController.super.<init>();
  ()
}, symbol=StatusController.<init>, symbol.overrides=List()
```

So as you can see, after `typer` phase, method symbol `StatusController.getPath` overrides method symbol `GenericController.getPath` and `StatusController.save` overrides `GenericController.save`. And after `jvm` phase `StatusController.getPath` again overrides `GenericController.getPath` but it's bridge `StatusController.save` instead of ordinary `StatusController.save` that overrides `GenericController.save`. So I guess you confused symbol of bridge method with symbol of ordinary method.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I appreciate it! I am learning about compiler plugins as I go.

Comment: @user328 Welcome. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @user328 Did you manage to fix your compiler plugin?